# "localhost" inside static assets url on vue production mode

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, firebase-hosting

I did deploy my project to Firebase Hosting but the problem is that I get the following error on some request that request image. However my images are shown perfectly on my site:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Note that the path in the request contains `http://localhost:8000/img/` instead of `http://mydomain/img/`

This is minimal example of how I do define my image paths:

```
<v-img :src="require('@/assets/img/sellings.png')" />
```

I do have enabled the history (`mode: 'history'`) mode in router

Also in firebase.json config I do have the following:

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "dist/",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
       }
    ]
}
```

And in `vue.config.js` I do have the following:

```
global.__rootDirname = path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
```

What causes the issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you start the server ?

Comment: @MickaelB. on localhost I do `npm run serve` and before I deploy to production I do `npm run build`

Comment: It's probably a CORS error, protocols, domains and ports must match. Eventhought the final target is the same, the written address and the current URL are compared at some point.

Comment: What's the command in `npm run serve`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `vue-cli-service` you can use `--host` or `--public` arguments

```
$ npx vue-cli-service serve --help
    --host         specify host (default: 0.0.0.0)
    --public       specify the public network URL for the HMR client
```

So try to run

```
npx vue-cli-service serve --public mydomain
```

or

```
npm run serve -- --public mydomain
```

Comment: The problem is in production mode. I have no problems on localhost.

Comment: Your given commands would all serve my application locally. There is something with `npm run build` which generates wrong urls.

Comment: What's in your `npm run build` ?

Comment: `npm run build` is command that builds project into static assets. This is not my written command.

Comment: Check the `package.json` file, go to `scripts` property and then go to `build` and copy paste what's written there. And to the same for the the `serve` property

Comment: I do have default commands: `vue-cli-service build` `vue-cli-service serve`, no flags etc.

Comment: You should use relative path instead then and remove the `require` in the src. Then define the `publicPath` in `vue.config.js`. See https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath

Comment: Since I am using history mode it is recommended to avoid public relativePath. I also have `global.__rootDirname = path.join(__dirname, 'dist')`in `vue.config.js`